Batik issue in Converting WMF Images to SVG
I am trying to convert WMF Images to SVG using Batik in Java.
Code:
package org.example;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.wmf.tosvg.WMFTranscoder;

public class WmfImagesToPng1 {

    public static void convert(String wmfFilePath, String svgFilePath) throws IOException, TranscoderException {

        File wmfFile = new File(wmfFilePath);
        File svgFile = new File(svgFilePath);        

        WMFTranscoder transcoder = new WMFTranscoder();

        // Set transcoder hints
        transcoder.addTranscodingHint(WMFTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) 800); // Set output width
        transcoder.addTranscodingHint(WMFTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) 600); // Set output height

        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(wmfFile));

        // Use StringWriter to capture SVG output
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(writer);

        // Perform transcoding
        transcoder.transcode(input, output);

        // Write SVG content to file
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(svgFile)) {
            fileWriter.write(writer.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TranscoderException {
        // Replace these paths with your actual file paths
        String wmfFilePath = "029.wmf";
        String svgFilePath = "output.svg";

        convert(wmfFilePath, svgFilePath);

        System.out.println("WMF file converted to SVG successfully!");
    }
}

The SVG file is generated however, the path attribute in it is always like below
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
          'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg stroke-dasharray="none" shape-rendering="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="'Dialog'" width="800" text-rendering="auto" fill-opacity="1" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" color-interpolation="auto" color-rendering="auto" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" font-size="12px" viewBox="0 0 800 619" fill="black" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke="black" image-rendering="auto" stroke-miterlimit="10" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" contentStyleType="text/css" font-style="normal" height="619" stroke-width="1" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-weight="normal" stroke-opacity="1"
><!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--><defs id="genericDefs"
  /><g
  ><g fill="rgb(102,51,0)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="rgb(102,51,0)"
    ><path d="MNaN NaN LNaN NaN LNaN NaN LNaN NaN LNaN NaN.....

Link to the sample WMF Image I tried .It is not image specific seems to occur for any WMF Image.
Why is output SVG containing NaN ?
My WMF image is valid as it renders fine in multiple WMF Viewers. Does it mean batik doesn't support all WMF Images?
I am using batik-transcoder-1.17 & batik-codec-1.17 jars(latest as of Date) for WMF to Svg conversion.
Any help is really appreciated

Probably a good idea to link to the .wmf image or even inline it (better)

@g00se Had edited question now & Added the link to the sample wmf image I tried.

Might simply be buggy. I had to resort to inkscape -o x.svg sample.wmf

@g00se But the problem doesn't seem to be file specific, it occurs consistently with few other WMF images I tried as well. So it appears to be universal ? Does it mean batik doesn't have a working WMF to SVG convertor in them ?

Does it mean batik doesn't have a working WMF to SVG convertor in them ? Possibly. You should talk to its devs
